# How to remove tag from html with JavaScript in iphone UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Guys i have a html string like below;

```
<html>
   <head><title></title></head>
   <body>i wanna remove <span name="Note">this</span> tag</body>
</html>
```

i use this javascript code:

```
NSString *str = @"function f(){
   var nodes = document.getElementsByName('Note');
   alert(nodes.length); // it returns node count correctly
   for(var i = nodes.length - 1;i >= 0;i--){
       var node = nodes[i];
       if (node){
         node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
       }
   }
}f();";

[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
```

result is :

```
<html>
   <head><title></title></head>
   <body>i wanna remove tag</body>
</html>
```

how can i remove only tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
NSString *str = @"function f(){
   var doc = document;
   var nodes = doc.getElementsByClassName('Note');
   alert(nodes.length); // it returns node count correctly
   for(var i = nodes.length - 1;i >= 0;i--){
       var node = nodes[i];
       if (node){
         //node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
         node.parentNode.replaceChild(doc.createTextNode(node.innerHTML), node);
       }
   }
}f();";
```

but this will cause weird results if you got nested tags like `<span class="Note">foo<span>bar</span></span>` if remove the class is enough guess you could do something like this:

```
NSString *str = @"function f(){
   var doc = document;
   var nodes = doc.getElementsByClassName('Note');
   alert(nodes.length); // it returns node count correctly
   for(var i = nodes.length - 1;i >= 0;i--){
       var node = nodes[i];
       if (node){
         //node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
         node.className = '';
       }
   }
}f();";
```

Edit:

```
NSString *str = @"function f(){
   var doc = document;
   var aux = doc.createElement('span');
   //alert(nodes.length); // it returns node count correctly
   for(var nodes = doc.getElementsByClassName('Note'); nodes && (nodes.length > 0); doc.getElementsByClassName('Note')){
       var node = nodes[0];
       if (node){
         aux.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
         for (var el = aux.firstChild, next = el.nextSibling; el; el = next, next = next ? next.nextSibling : null){
            var tmp = node.parentNode.insertBefore(el, node);
         }
         node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
       }
   }
}f();";
```

Comment: this is gonna work in e-reader for write note to selected text..
and, if i couldnt remove tag which added by me, there will be lots of `<span>` tags.. i need more to remove known tag completely

Comment: If you really need remove the tags I will have a new version of the code. You could have a look if you need it.

Comment: Here I have trying to create a highlighting the text and retrieve the highlighted text when ever close and open the book.I literally highlighted the text but i don't know how to store and retrieve it.Could you help me please