# How to remove a div tag in html String in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview

I m extracting an html string using `@"document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content')[0].innerHTML";` and i was successful in getting the html response where i m storing it in a string ,the problem is i need to remove a div named as "collections-form" on the html response from the string.could you guys help me out.below is the code.

```
    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1 {
    NSLog(@"finish");
    [activity hide:YES];
    NSString *app;

    if (currentPage == 3)
    app=@"<style>table {font-size:10px;}</style>";
    else app=@"<style>table {font-size:10px;}</style>";

    NSString *temp1 = @"document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content')[0].innerHTML; " ;

    NSString *class =[webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:temp1];

    NSString *localString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",class,app];

    [webView1 loadHTMLString:localString baseURL:nil];

    webView.hidden = NO;
    webView.delegate =nil; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is call js code which removes that element after content is loaded.

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"var element = document.getElementById('%@'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);",
         @"id2",
];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand]
```

And This is another way if you wish to use JavaScript

[How to remove tag from html with JavaScript in iphone UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806363/how-to-remove-tag-from-html-with-javascript-in-iphone-uiwebview)

Comment: Will this be apply for class, too?